# How To Use Strip Methods Across All Indexes of Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, strip

I have a series with each index containing an array of strings like below:

```
0 | ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3']
1 | ['value 4']
2 | ['value 1', 'value 3']
```

Basically what I want to do is call lstrip and rstrip on the square brackets to remove them from each indexed string then run a frequency count across all of the items to get the total counts of each unique value across all of the indexes in the series. I'm able to strip any single index using:

```
x = df1['Column'][0].lstrip('[').rstrip(']') .     #[0] is index
```

which outputs

```
'value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3'
```

How would I iterate over each index to perform this function for all rows?

Essentially, if I just run a

```
x = df1['Column'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

for this dataset, some of the unique values in the output have '[' or ']' in them if they are the first or last value in the array for that given row which throws off the frequency counts as instead of totaling a unique value, the output would be something like this:

```
['value 1' | 35
'value 1' | 20
```

instead of

```
'value 1' | 55
```

Comment: Can you create code to create you input dataframe?  I suspect you can use `explode` instead of string manipulation.

Comment: I'm pulling data from the spotify api. The column I'm focused on in my dataframe is pulling genres from the artist object which can be found here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/artists/get-artist/

Comment: The fact that you’re able to _remove the brackets_ like that makes me think that the contents of the Series are **strings, not lists**. Can you check? Also, please share a proper [mcve].

Comment: Yes, they are in fact arrays of strings according to the spotify api documentation.

Comment: `df['Column'].str[1:-1]`?

Comment: How about `x = df['Column'].str.strip('[]').split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()`?

Comment: @Błotosmętek i get the error 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @QuangHoang that doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, dropped one `str` - this should work: `x = df['Column'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()`

Comment: @Błotosmętek this worked perfect thank you so much!